# How do I get the Kendo editor to update from angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following code.

html

```html
<textarea ng-bind-html="html" style="height:440px" kendo-editor k-   options="editorOptions"></textarea>
```

JS

```js
angular.module('SplashApp', ['ngRoute', 'kendo.directives', 'ngSanitize'])
    .controller("MainController", function ($scope, $location, $route, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.html = "<h1>Kendo Editor</h1>\n\n" +
          "<p>Note that 'change' is triggered when the editor loses focus.\n" +
              "<br /> That's when the Angular scope gets updated.</p>";
});
```

When the page renders it is fine. If the user updates the page it also makes the changes to $scope.html. BUT if I change the $scope.html from javascript the contents of the editor do not change. How do I get this to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've created a dojo and could reproduce your app accordingly. And created a button to change the html in the controller.

```
 angular.module('SplashApp', ['kendo.directives', 'ngSanitize'])
        .controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.html = "<h1>Kenessssdo Editor</h1>\n\n" +
              "<p>Note that 'change' is triggered when the editor loses focus.\n" +
                  "<br /> That's when the Angular scope gets updated.</p>";
                $scope.addHtml = function(){
                                    $scope.html+= "<br>ahahahahhahah";
            };
    });
```

[Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aWaVe)

Everything was fine. Is your syntax is correct?

Comment: Your Dojo was great - thanks. I had used the example on Telerik and the difference was they show <textarea ng-bind-html="html" style="width: 100%; height: 5em"></textarea> as the correct syntax. Your example added ng-model="html". When I add that it works correctly. Thanks so much.